# Monodroid Layout Folder support

Tags: visual-studio, android-layout, xamarin.android

I'd like to use qualifiers on my layout folders as per the android documentation, but the designer in VS doesn't seem to support them. For example layout-w600dp doesn't get sent to the emulator; the default axml file from the layout folder is used.

Does anyone know if these settings are supported in Monodroid? If so, how do you make them take effect?

Comment: I have only tried with hdpi, mdpi and those work.

Answer (score 1):

I think w600dp requires a certain api level to work - maybe 3.2 - see http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Comment: Yes, it does. But, the designer in Visual Studio seems to manage the folders itself. The layout-w600dp folder contents don't seem to get packaged regardless of the api level.